# Tooltip gives wrong values in my heatmap diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to create a toolip on my Heatmap Graph.The Heatmap Graph and the Tooltip are working but the Tooltip is giving me the wrong values. The output of the Tooltip always gives me the value:

> "The exact value is: undefined"

Also in the Debug console its giving me a Message:

> "rbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

What is wrong here?

```
    var tooltip = d3.select("#container")
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .style("background", "#ffffff")
```

```
svg.selectAll()
      .data(mapData.data, function(d) {return d.group +':'+ d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.variable) })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.group) })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colour(d.value)})
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      })
      .on("mousemove", function(d){
        tooltip.html("The exact value is: " + d.value)
        return tooltip.style("top", (d3.pointer(this)[1]) + "px").style("left",(d3.pointer(this)[0]+30) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function(d){
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      })
```

```
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  <div id="container"> </id>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```js
svg.selectAll()
      .data(mapData.data, function(d) {return d.group +':'+ d.variable;})
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.variable) })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.group) })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colour(d.value)})
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
      })
      .on("mousemove", function(d){
        tooltip.html("The exact value is: " + d.value)
        return tooltip.style("top", (d3.pointer(this)[1]) + "px").style("left",(d3.pointer(this)[0]+30) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function(d){
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
      })
```

with:

```js
 svg.selectAll("rect")     
      .on("mouseenter", () => tooltip.style("visibility", "visible"))
      .on("mousemove", (e, d) => {
        tooltip.html("The exact value is: " + d.value);
        tooltip
        .style("top", `${e.layerY + 24}px`)
        .style("left", `${e.layerX + 24}px`);
      })
      .on("mouseleave", () => tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden"))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. But what does these mean? `.style("top", ${e.layerY + 24}px)`
        `.style("left", ${e.layerX + 24}px);`

Comment: `e` is a mouse event passed to the `mousemove`. `layerX` and `layerY` are the current cursor coordinates within the parent element. I add 24 pixels to offset the tooltip from the cursor and prevent blinking. You can change this number to a more convenient one

Comment: You can also adjust position to the hitmap cell (`<rect>`) instead of the cursor

Comment: What does the $ means here?

Comment: Template literals : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals  The ES6 way to format strings